# I want to kill a forever task which has been called by an object which has been killed later

Tags: system-verilog

```
program ass_arry();
    int i;
    int j;
    class u3_param;
        int j;
        task print(int s);
            forever begin
                #10us;
                $display("%t  %M:the object number=%d  ",$time,s);
            end
        endtask
    endclass

u3_param o_u3_param;//creating object
initial
begin
    o_u3_param=new();//i am creating object handle here
    o_u3_param.print(1);//i am calling task which is forever
 end
 initial    
 begin
     #20us;
     o_u3_param=null; 
     #50us;
    $finish();
 end
```

endprogram

//Hi all i am creating object of class u3_param and i used two parallel threads one thread calls the task of the object of u3_param  which is forever,in another parallel thread after  waiting some simulation delay i deleting the object by assigning to null.i thought the task of the object which is forever has to be stop but it is still running,i want to know how to kill called task.

Answer (score 0):

Your simulator does not apear to be following the standard. File a issue to your simulator provider. Garbage collection on unreferenced objects has been part of the SystemVerilog standard since classes were added in Accellera's SystemVerilog 3.1.

The section that covers "Memory management" (by LRM: IEEE 1800-2005 § 7.26, IEEE 1800-2009 § 7.26, [IEEE 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 8.29, Accellera's SystemVerilog 3.1 / 3.1a § 11.26) covers a scenario near identical to the SO's questions. Quoting *all* the LRMs:

> Users do not need to worry about dangling references, premature deallocation, or memory leaks. The system shall automatically reclaim any object that is no longer being used. In the preceding example, all that users do is assign `null` to all the variables referencing handle *obj* when they no longer need it. An object shall not be reclaimed while there are outstanding references to that object in any active scope, or pending nonblocking assignments to non-static members of that object.

If you are stuck with the bug, then you'll need a stopping mechanize, ex:

```
// ...
class Object;
  bit kill;
  task run();
    fork : run_thread
      wait(kill==1) disable run_thread;
      forever #5ns $display("I'm still alive @ %t",$time);
    join_none
  endtask
endclass
// ...
Object obj;
initial begin
  obj = new();
  obj.run();
  #1us;   obj.kill = 1;
  #20ns;  obj =  null;
  #20ns;  $display("End @ %t",$time);
  $finish;
end
// ...
```

Comment: @user3181456, "Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question," http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers